# FactoryBot ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have four models and I am using SQL Server 2017.

Factory bot: 4.11.1

Rails: 5.0.7

Email filter will have child filters which will be used to send email campaign. And EmailFilterRecord will store the email addresses for that campaign.

```
class EmailFilter < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :Email_Filter
  self.primary_key = :Id

  has_many :email_filter_details, foreign_key: 'Email_Filter_Id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :email_campaigns, foreign_key: 'email_filter_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_filter_details, allow_destroy: true
end

class EmailFilterDetail < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :Email_Filter_Details
  belongs_to :email_filter, primary_key: 'Id'
end

class EmailCampaign < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :Email_Campaign

  belongs_to :email_filter, primary_key: 'Id'
  has_many :email_filter_records, foreign_key: 'email_campaign_id', dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_filter_records, allow_destroy: true
end

class EmailFilterRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :Email_FilterRecords

  belongs_to :email_campaign
end
```

Factories:

```
FactoryBot.define do

  factory :email_filter do
    Name              { 'First Filter' }
    Description       { 'First Filter Description' }

    factory :all_active_mobile_services do
      after(:create) do |email_filter|
        create(:email_filter_detail, email_filter: email_filter)
      end
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do

  factory :email_filter_detail do
    Filter_Type { 'ServiceType' }
    Filter_Value { 'MB' }
  end
end
```

If I do this

```
create(:all_active_mobile_services)
```

I am getting this error:

```
  ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
  can't write unknown attribute `email_filter_id`
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Does `email_filter_details` table have a column `email_filter_id` to begin with? (make sure you run your migrations on the test environment too)

Comment: I have Email_Filter_Id in Email_Filter_Details table. And I wrote this in EmailFilter model: "has_many :email_filter_details, foreign_key: 'Email_Filter_Id', dependent: :destroy". So I think ActiveRecord should understand which is the foreign_key, right?

Answer (score 1):

OK, got the solution. I have added `belongs_to :email_filter, foreign_key: 'Email_Filter_Id'` in `email_filter_detail` model and now it's working.